# Is it bad idea to use Socket on servlet?

Tags: java, sockets, servlets

I have Web Application server, which takes parameters and pass them to Client class. When calling the exactly same Client class in normal Java Application, everything works fine, but when calling the Client from servlet, the Client-Server conversation always hangs for either of two reasons:

1. Certain message (always the same one) sent from server is oddly formated and Client cannot process it.
2. If the message aforesaid is correctly formated, when the Client responds to it, the server never replies.

Here is the part of Client responsible for the connection:

```
    int key;
    int messCount=0;
    int count=0;
    ConnCrypto m = new ConnCrypto();
    String[] s = {};
    GameCrypto g = new GameCrypto(s);
    int i = g.init();
    Socket tcp;
    BufferedReader reader;
    BufferedWriter writer;
    CryptHandler crypt= new CryptHandler();
    static int err=0;

    void setup() throws IOException {
        tcp = new Socket(serverIp, serverPort);
        InputStream InputStream = tcp.getInputStream();
        OutputStream OutputStream = tcp.getOutputStream();
        InputStreamReader InputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(InputStream);
        OutputStreamWriter OutputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream);
        reader = new BufferedReader(InputStreamReader);
        writer = new BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter);
    }

    void send(String z) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Send:\t" + z);
        z = m.encrypt(z);
        writer.write(z);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();
    }

    void crypt(String z) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Send:\t" + z);
        z = crypt.crypt(z);
        z = "d " + messCount + " "+(char)1 + z;
        send(z);
        messCount++;
    }

    void crypt2(String z) throws IOException {
        z = g.encrypt(z);
        z = "d " + messCount + " " + z;
        send(z);
        messCount++;
    }

    String recv() throws IOException {
        char chr;
        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
        while((chr=(char)reader.read())!=0x0A)
            sb.append(chr);
        String str=sb.toString();
        if (key != 0) {
            str = m.decrypt(str);
            int gg = str.charAt(0);
            if (gg == 100) {
                System.out.print("Raw:\t"+str);
                str = "d " + crypt.decrypt(str.substring(5));
            }
        } 
        else if (str.charAt(0) == 99) {
            key = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(5));
            m.init(i, key);
        }
        System.out.println("Recv:\t" + str);
        return str;
    }
```

So is is it bad to use the Socket object, or is there something else in my code I should avoid?

Comment: Your code looks pretty bad and judging by the style you're a former C programmer or something? Where are you creating the threads and using that class? There's not enough code to see what's the major flaw in your design. As to your title however, no, it's really not a good idea to start creating Sockets inside servlets.

Comment: String is not a container for binary data. The result of encryption is a byte[], unless you're base64-encoding them, which you don't state. If you want to read lines, BuferedReader already does that, but you can't assume that an encrypted message ends with an unencrypted NL character and doesn't contain one in the middle.

Comment: @Kayaman This is my first try on servlets and I haven't used Threads yet. What would you recommend instead of using Socket?

Comment: @EJP The encryption classes are long an unnecessary for the problem in my opinion. The encryption works so that every message is a string with any kind of characters but NL/LF and they end to NL without LF. I first tried with readline(), but the behavier didn't change. The thing is that the same code works fine when called from normal applications, but not when called inside servlet.